# Dataframe produced from .json file, the "date" column becomes altered (pictures shown) how do I prevent this?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm rather new to python and I've been given a data science assignment for which I have to choose an API (chose global-warming.org) and then clean, parse and store the data as a json file, then load it into a dataframe for further analysis. Then I have to analyse the data using matplotlib etc. I have decided I will extract each of the API's for the greenhouse gases (CH4, CO2, N2O), cut each of the datasets down to just March 2020 - present and then see if I can analyse how the pandemic has influenced greenhouse gas production. I am struggling however, to load the initial methane data (taken monthly for each year) into a clean dataframe using the json file I have stored it in. As the pictures below show, the "date" column seems to change drastically from the e.g. 2020.4 format to this format: 1970-01-01 00:33:40.700 ?

I would be so, so, grateful if someone could give me an idea how to get around this. If anyone had any general suggestions as to how to go about the assignment too I would be in your debt, but I am currently stuck on this one problem and figuring it out would be a huge help in itself, I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing...

Thanks so much!

`yearly_methane.json` file example lines:

```
[{"date": "1983.7", "average": "1625.9", "trend": "1634.6", "averageUnc": "2.4", "trendUnc": "1.5"}, {"date": "1983.8", "average": "1628.1", "trend": "1635.3", "averageUnc": "2.9", "trendUnc": "1.4"}, {"date": "1983.9", "average": "1638.4", "trend": "1636.0", "averageUnc": "2.2", "trendUnc": "1.3"}, {"date": "1983.10", "average": "1644.8", "trend": "1636.7", "averageUnc": "1.4", "trendUnc": "1.3"}, {"date": "1983.11", "average": "1642.6", "trend": "1637.5", "averageUnc": "0.8", "trendUnc": "1.2"}, {"date": "1983.12", "average": "1639.4", "trend": "1638.3", "averageUnc": "0.9", "trendUnc": "1.1"}, {"date": "1984.1", "average": "1638.6", "trend": "1639.2", "averageUnc": "1.9", "trendUnc": "1.0"}, {"date": "1984.2", "average": "1638.8", "trend": "1640.1", "averageUnc": "2.0", "trendUnc": "0.9"}, {"date": "1984.3", "average": "1640.7", "trend": "1641.1", "averageUnc": "1.6", "trendUnc": "0.8"}, {"date": "1984.4", "average": "1643.7", "trend": "1642.1", "averageUnc": "1.9", "trendUnc": "0.8"}, {"date": "1984.5", "average": "1642.9", "trend": "1643.1", "averageUnc": "1.1", "trendUnc": "0.7"}, {"date": "1984.6", "average": "1639.6", "trend": "1644.2", "averageUnc": "0.9", "trendUnc": "0.7"}, {"date": "1984.7", "average": "1637.7", "trend": "1645.3", "averageUnc": "1.2", "trendUnc": "0.7"}, {"date": "1984.8", "average": "1641.3", "trend": "1646.4", "averageUnc": "1.6", "trendUnc": "0.6"}, {"date": "1984.9", "average": "1650.4", "trend": "1647.6", "averageUnc": "1.3", "trendUnc": "0.6"}, {"date": "1984.10", "average": "1654.4", "trend": "1648.7", "averageUnc": "1.5", "trendUnc": "0.6"}, {"date": "1984.11", "average": "1653.6", "trend": "1649.8", "averageUnc": "1.2",
```

[Image - Creating the initial json file (for reference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV0hG.png)

[Creating the desired dataframe - the date column becomes altered?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnLbI.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your post and paste (as text) a few sample lines from your `yearly_methane.json` file.

Comment: Have just done that there, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `convert_dates=False` to bypass the automatic parsing and `dtype={'date': str}` to force the `date` column as a raw string:

```py
df = pd.read_json('yearly_methane.json', convert_dates=False, dtype={'date': str})
```

|  | date | average | trend | averageUnc | trendUnc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1983.7 | 1625.9 | 1634.6 | 2.4 | 1.5 |
| 1 | 1983.8 | 1628.1 | 1635.3 | 2.9 | 1.4 |
| 2 | 1983.9 | 1638.4 | 1636.0 | 2.2 | 1.3 |
| 3 | 1983.10 | 1644.8 | 1636.7 | 1.4 | 1.3 |

Then convert the `%Y.%m` dates into `datetime` objects manually using [**`pd.to_datetime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```py
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y.%m')
```

|  | date | average | trend | averageUnc | trendUnc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1983-07-01 | 1625.9 | 1634.6 | 2.4 | 1.5 |
| 1 | 1983-08-01 | 1628.1 | 1635.3 | 2.9 | 1.4 |
| 2 | 1983-09-01 | 1638.4 | 1636.0 | 2.2 | 1.3 |
| 3 | 1983-10-01 | 1644.8 | 1636.7 | 1.4 | 1.3 |